# Javascript dropdownlist on button/click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I'm trying to display an image when the user selects an option in the dropdown list, the image will then be displayed after button click. This is my idea on how to do this but I'm not quite sure if its correct so I'm asking others for opinion's.

Here's my code and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bc6Et/1546/

html

```
<select name="" id="dropdownlist" size="">
    <option value="img1">Image</option>
    <option value="img2">Image</option>
    <option value="img3">Image</option>
    <option value="">so on and so forth</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Show Image" onclick="showimg()" class="button">
```

javascript/jquery

```
 function showimg() {
        var q = document.getElementById("dropdownlist");
        var selected = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value;

        var src = "/var/www/VAA/img";
        if (selected === img1) {
            show_image("/var/www/VAA/img/img1.png");
        }

        elseif(selected === img2) {
            show_image("/var/www/VAA/img2.png");
        }
    }

    function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
```

Or I could use case/break switch statements instead of if/else. Appreciate all the help tnx oh and 1 more thing the images are on my desktop thought you might need that info

Comment: /var/www/VAA/img u forget to give extension /var/www/VAA/img.png

Comment: oh tnx I'll edit it, do you think my process or solution is correct?

Comment: "if (q === img1)" seems to be an error, what is img1? a variable? must it be == "img1" ?

Comment: it should actually be `if (selected == 'img1')`

Comment: img1 is the value of the 1st image in the dropdown list, if my logic is correct (which I'm not quite sure) once the user clicks for example the 1st one on the dropdown list, function showimg() will get the value that is selected then proceed to the other function

Comment: @abhitalks I'll try it tnx

Comment: here are multiple answer and every answer is half correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a if statement for each images maybe you can try something like this?

```
<option value="name_of_your_image">Image</option>
```

And then call your function:

```
var src = "/var/www/VAA/"+selected+".png";   
show_image(src);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bc6Et/1558/

I think this is a better option if you have a lot of images.

Comment: sir with this method the values of the option will be changed to the names og the images instead? Is my understanding correct? <option value="name of image in the folder">Image</option>

Comment: Yes. If the extension is the same for all your images you can add it in your script like i did in the exemple. If extensions are different you can give it in the value of your option : <option value="image_name.extension">

Answer (score 1):

You were looking into the wrong variable. q is always the dropdown element and has nothing to do directly with which option is selected and/or their respective value.
img1 and img2 must be declared as a string since they are no variables.

```
function showimg() {
    var q = document.getElementById("dropdownlist");
    var selected = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value;

    console.log(selected);

var src = "/var/www/VAA/img";
if (selected === "img1") {
    show_image("/var/www/VAA/img");
}

else if (selected === "img2") {
    show_image("/var/www/VAA/img");
    }
}

function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    console.log(src);
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc6Et/1545/)

Comment: i meant how is that considered that image is `png` or `jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors

```
function showimg() {
    var q = document.getElementById("dropdownlist");
    var selected = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value;

    var src = "/var/www/VAA/img";
    if (selected === "img1") {
        //_____^__________ 
        show_image("/var/www/VAA/img");
    }

    else if(selected === "img2") {
    //__^__________^______
        show_image("/var/www/VAA/img");
    }
}

function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/Bc6Et/1557/)

Comment: `q !== selected` i hope you get it. see alex's answer, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It would work but you will need one if condition for every image you have.
Why don't you put all images on the same folder, and build the imagepath concatenating strings?

```
src = "/var/www/VAA/";
var selected = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value;
show_image(src+selected);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion so that you don't have to have a lot of conditional statements for identifying which image to show: what if you place the image src (or maybe just the filename if you want) as the value of the select box's options, like so:

```
<select name="image" id="dropdownlist">
  <option value="/source/for/image1.png">Image 1</option>
  <option value="/source/for/image2.png">Image 2</option>
  <option value="/source/for/image3.png">Image 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Show Image" class="button" />
```

And then you can modify your jQuery code like so:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  var image = $('<img src="' + $('#dropdownlist').val() + '" />');
  $('body').append(image);
});
```